# Trying to manipulate the returned json from a cURL call

Tags: php, json, curl

This problem is confusing me. Here is my code:

```
try {
    //API Url
    $url =   'https:<REST OF URL>';

    //Initiate cURL.
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    //The JSON data.
    $jsonData = array(
        'UserName' => '<HIDDEN>',
        'Password' => '<HIDDEN>'
    );

    //Encode the array into JSON.
    $jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);

    //Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    //Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

    //Set the content type to application/json
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    //Execute the request
    $content = curl_exec($ch);

catch(Exception $e) {   
    trigger_error(sprintf(
        'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
        $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
        E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Im using a browser to run the php script and the output seems to be json format, which is what i need. However when i add json decode and try to print_r or var_dump the output, i simply get a boolean(true) or int(1), it doesnt want to take the data into an array. What is also odd and most likely related is that with the code above im not using print_r, or var_dump or even an echo and still it prints the json format to the screen?

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here is the json output, that appears on the screen:

```
 {"AvailableAdvisers":[{"AdviserId":"1345678","BusinessEntityName":"Bob Smith Finance","FullName":"Bob Smith"},{"AdviserId":"12345678","BusinessEntityName":"Globe Home Loans Pty Ltd","FullName":"Jane Doe"}],"FirstName":"Sam","LastName":"Sung","LendingPartnerStaffId":"12345674356","Locations":[{"LendingPartnerLocationId":"123467867647","Name":"Bank"},{"LendingPartnerLocationId":"12324354545","Name":"Jane Smith"}],"UserName":"Username"}
```

Comment: I see no subject to discuss. So you've got your `$content` - you `var_dump($content);` and it is `true` value, but you want convert true to what??? maybe you should just show us the code from other side? that generates the response to your request, or what service do you use? read documentation, probably you need to change some request parameters?

Comment: the browser shows the API returned a json string, therefore one would expect that json string to be the variable $content. However this is not the case, when you print_r($content) it simply shows the integer 1. So i need the json string to be $content, do you get what i mean?

Comment: no, absolutely no. 1. You do curl request 2. Request successfully executed and return something that you put into `$content` variable. 3. You did print this `$content` and you SEE that it is just `int(1)`. and..... somehow, I don't no on what reason you base your opinion, but you are sure that this response is incomplete. But facts say it is complete. :-) there is nothing to add :-)

Comment: Ok. I editted the post, when i run the code above, this is the output. Is it not json? where in my code have i set to echo/print this data? Doesnt this suggest that the returned json string is content of $content? However when i print_r($content), it is the value 1. In other words, which variable is holding the above json string??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, it seems I got your point.

So to get curl response into `$content` variable you probably have to add line:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

before your `curl_exec`

But the miracle how the curl response appear on the page is real enigma :-)

Comment: tell me about it, its a weird thing, how it appears on the page. OH well :P

Comment: :-))) good luck with your project! I have no idea how it could appear without any `echo` :-(